# Python script in Rundeck failing

Tags: rundeck

I have a python script on server_A that connects to server_B via SSH and calls a local rsync command to reset a directory B with a fresh set of files. Then the script on A proceeds to rsync over additional set of files to B. My hope was to run this on a schedule in Rundeck. However, it is erroring on me every time during run with this output. What am I doing wrong?

```
Remote command failed with exit status 1
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1
Execution failed: 9 in project Test: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [server_A: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1]}, Node failures: {server_A=[NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1]}, flow control: Continue, status: failed]
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit status 1 was returned by the command you called. What are you running?